# Error message while instaling magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9

i am trying to install Bulk Import+Export Orders to CSV but it is show an error

[image]

please help me to resolve this issuse

Answer (score 1):

Well the error is clear: the module requires PHP >= 5.2.0 and <= 5.6.12 and you're running 5.6.18.

My suggestion is to try to manually install that module, as Magento Connect double checks requirements and in your case, I highly doubt the module will break on 5.6.18.

You can use Freegento to download the module: http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Then upload the files to your website.